# Intellij IDEA "Project Structure ->Artifact" : Pre-processing and Post-processing missing

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, ant, artifact

I'm working in a new java project with Intellij IDEA 2021.2.3 (Community Edition).

When building a jar artifact I need to do pre processing & post processing at build time with an Ant script but I found relative tab missing in `Project Structure ->Artifacts`, as you can see in the following picture:

[image: Artifact dialog with no pre & post processing tab]

Another java project, few months older than the first one, has `Pre-processing` and `Post-processing` tabs in the same dialog as you can see in the following picture:

[image: Artifact dialog with pre & post processing tab]

How can I make these tabs available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-276464).

The fix is available in https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/.